# What is the meaning of '/' in following TIBCO expression

Tags: xpath, tibco, tibco-business-works

I have following code in Tibco business works module

```
$ES_GetInfo/root/pfx4:GetInformationAndPropertyDetailsResponse/pfx4:LicenseInfo/pfx4:CoreEnt/pfx4:Ent
[pfx4:Ent/pfx4:EntOfferingCode = $Read_DB_Data/group/ROW/EOC]
/pfx4:EntState = "Disabled"
```

I can understand it is comparing `"EntOfferingCode"` with `"EOC"`, but could not get the expression `"/pfx4:EntState = 'Disabled'"`?

As per the TIBCO, the whole expression returns a boolean value.

What is the meaning of `"/pfx4:entState='Disabled'"`. Is logical or conditional or something else?

Answer (score 0):

The whole expression is logical condition. The '/' is just xml schema elements separator in XPath (XML Path Language) syntax. You can start learning tibco xpath from here https://docs.tibco.com/pub/activematrix_businessworks/6.3.0/doc/html/GUID-D319018B-AA74-428D-A034-E477778AD2B6.html

The expression first filtering all the "Ent" nodes that have EntOfferingCode = $Read_DB_Data/group/ROW/EOC
then check if exists EntState = "Disabled" in filtered result

the expression can be replaced by

```
  not (empty($Start/pfx:GetInformationAndPropertyDetailsResponse/pfx:LicenseInfo/pfx:CoreEnt/pfx:Ent[ pfx:EntOfferingCode= "EOC" and pfx:EntState = "Disabled"]))
```

For example

if the schema is like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
     xmlns="http://www.tibco.com/schemas/TestProcess/Schema/Schema.xsd"
     targetNamespace="http://www.tibco.com/schemas/TestProcess/Schema/Schema.xsd"
     elementFormDefault="qualified"
     attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="GetInformationAndPropertyDetailsResponse">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="LicenseInfo" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="LicenseInfo">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="CoreEnt" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="CoreEnt">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="Ent" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="Ent">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="EntOfferingCode" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="EntState" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Expression return true for:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<GetInformationAndPropertyDetailsResponse xmlns = "http://www.tibco.com/schemas/TestProcess/Schema/Schema.xsd">
    <LicenseInfo>
        <CoreEnt>
            <Ent>
                <EntOfferingCode>EOC</EntOfferingCode>
                <EntState>Disabled</EntState>
            </Ent>
        </CoreEnt>
    </LicenseInfo>
</GetInformationAndPropertyDetailsResponse>
```

Expression return false for:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<GetInformationAndPropertyDetailsResponse xmlns = "http://www.tibco.com/schemas/TestProcess/Schema/Schema.xsd">
    <LicenseInfo>
        <CoreEnt>
            <Ent>
                <EntOfferingCode>EOC</EntOfferingCode>
                <EntState>Enabled</EntState>
            </Ent>
            <Ent>
                <EntOfferingCode>EOC1</EntOfferingCode>
                <EntState>Disabled</EntState>
            </Ent>
        </CoreEnt>
    </LicenseInfo>
</GetInformationAndPropertyDetailsResponse>
```

if you just use

```
$ES_GetInfo/root/pfx4:GetInformationAndPropertyDetailsResponse/pfx4:LicenseInfo/pfx4:CoreEnt/pfx4:Ent/pfx4:EntState = "Disabled"
```

it will return true for both examples

Answer (score 0):

If your question is what does the xslt expression mean, it is basically checking the following:

1. For all LicenseInfo/CoreEnt/Ent,
2. where Ent/EntOfferingCode = EOC value from the DB
3. check if the corresponding Enstate is Disabled or not
4. if Disabled, output true, else output false.